# Incorrect output for check existing file in upload in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

With this asp net page upload file in C# I need to check for duplicates.

I accept 3 files in upload on the server.

[image]

After uploading the new 3 files on the server, I have tried to upload the same file 3 files now existing on the server.

For 3 files jpg existing on the server the response code on the `Label` is incorrect because is :

> File exist IMG0006A.jpg

And not

> File exist IMG0002A.jpg, IMG0005A.jpg, IMG0006A.jpg

What's the problem ?

Why if I have in the code `foreach` in `Label` the output is only for last existing file ?

My code below, thank you in advance for any help.

```
if (File.Exists(theFileName))
{
    objDir = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("\\images\\));
    objFI = objDir.GetFiles("*.*");
    iFileCnt = 0;

    if (objFI.Length > 0)
    {
        foreach (FileInfo file in objFI)
        {
            if (file.Name.ToString() == Path.GetFileName(theFileName))
            {
                lblFileList.Text = "File exist " + Path.GetFileName(theFileName);
                iFileCnt += 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't **add** text to the label. You **set** it in each iteration.

Comment: @J.Steen Thank you, I am sorry but I don't understand your suggestion; how to do print on web page when the file is duplicate ?

Comment: You're overwriting the value of your label in each loop of your foreach. You're not adding to it. Figure out a way to do that, instead.

Comment: Its obvious as you have assigned a new value to the Label. Just use += instead in the line lblFileList.Text = "File exist " + Path.GetFileName(theFileName);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Jonathan's answer. He is checking for just one file name i.e. theFileName. You should loop through all your three files:
Assuming that fileNames is the list of your three file names.

```
int iFileCount = 0;
foreach (string fileName in fileNames)
{
    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(fileName)) continue;

    if(iFileCount <= 0)
    {
         lblFileList.Text = "File exist " + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileName);
    }
    else
    {
         lblFileList.Text += ", " + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileName);
    }
    ++iFileCount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
        if (File.Exists(theFileName))
        {
            objDir = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("\\images\\));
            objFI = objDir.GetFiles("*.*");

            if (objFI.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (FileInfo file in objFI)
                {
                    if (file.Name.ToString() == Path.GetFileName(theFileName))
                    {
                        if (iFileCnt == 0)
                        {
                            lblFileList.Text = "File exist " + Path.GetFileName(theFileName);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            lblFileList.Text += ", " + Path.GetFileName(theFileName);

                        }
                        iFileCnt += 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Note that iFileCnt = 0 needs to be set earlier, otherwise for every new file it is 0.
If I understand what you are doing correctly, however, it would be better to get your list of existing files earlier, rather than refreshing it each time. All you need to do, is add each successful file to the FileInfo array, to ensure that the list is complete.

Comment: Thank you but the output in `Label` is not changed, only last duplicate file.

Comment: Can you post a fuller extract please?